# mpir.dll was not found when try to run gmp

Tags: c++, gmp

I use Visual Studio Community 2017 x64, Windows 10, for C++.

I cannot run gmp code because of the following error:

> the code execution cannot proceed because mpir.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What happened when you tried to reinstall the program?

Comment: looks like you need to either find why mpir.dll is missing or actually try doing what the error message says and reinstalling the program.

Comment: ***i cannot run gmp code because of this error*** You probably did not put `mpir.dll` in one of the folders that is in your system `PATH` environment variable or add an entry for it to your `PATH`.

Comment: I already reinstall the program, but the same error happen

Comment: Did you try to locate the file it is asking for? Is in in your `PATH`?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the "Debug" build option in VS, simply place the "mpir.dll" file inside your "Debug" folder, next to the generated executable. This will allow the program to find it.

Alternatively, you can place the file in a system directory/PATH, so you don't need to copy it over when creating more programs using GMP.